# Why do I need to return the value outside the request when using sync requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

I have a question about sync requests.

Background: I need to get the userID of the user immediately before checkout. If userID is null or zero I will force the user to login. I decided to use the synchronous request. I understand the difference between async and sync requests. However I don't understand why the first code below does not work, but the second does.

```
...
UserId = GetUserId();
...

function GetUserId()
{
  var jsonRequest = new Request({url: myurl, async: false, onComplete: function(result) {return result;}}).get();
}
```

When I use the code above, I get UserId = undefined. However it works when I use the code below

```
...
UserId = GetUserId();
...

function GetUserId()
{
  var resultreturned;
  var jsonRequest = new Request({url: myurl, async: false, onComplete: function(result) {resultreturned = result;}}).get();
  return resultreturned;
}
```

It seems to me that in the first code, the processing does not stop even though I used the async:false. In the second code it works.

Does anyone know why?

In addition, is there a way to access the returned id without using the var resultreturned? Can I access the return using something like

return jsonRequest.value or jsonRequest.result or something else?

Thank you.

Comment: Why, exactly, did you go with a synchronous request? Is there some reason an async request won't work?

Comment: Because if I go with the async request the code does not stop while it is waiting for the userId to be returned. The system will think there is no userId and will show the login screen. I recognize that AJAX was created as an async process. However in this case I don't think it would work as an async request. Thanks.

Comment: Why couldn't you use a callback to displays the login screen when the asynchronous request returns, rather than when `GetUserId` returns?

Comment: Because I am checking for the userId immediately before saving the information to the database. I want to save only if the user is still logged. If he is no longer logged I want him to login. Does it make sense?

Comment: That doesn't show why you need to use a synchronous request, merely that you must get a response before the computation can proceed. The save doesn't need to happen when `GetUserId` returns. Put the logic to check the user ID and save the info or show the login form in a callback, as outlined in my answer.

Comment: I understand what you did. However aren't you also hanging the processing until a response from the request? It seems to me that both methods would have the exact same result - hanging the processing until we get a response. Am I missing something? Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my questions. I really appreciate.

Comment: Any processing other than the checkout-or-login can continue, which is the only computation that must wait. Synchronous requests can block more than your scripts; they can also block the UI, giving the appearance that the browser has frozen.

Comment: I see. I will try your implementation then. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version of `GetUserId` doesn't return anything. Simple as that. That the anonymous function passed as the completion handler returns something doesn't matter; its return value is passed to some internal mootools function and is ignored.

As for accessing the result, the base XMLHttpRequest object should be accessible as the `xhr` property of the Request object (though this doesn't appear to be part of [Request's public interface](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request)), and the response (in turn) is accessible as the [`responseText`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-responsetext-attribute) property of the XHR object. In short, try:

```
jsonRequest.xhr.responseText
```

However, this shouldn't be necessary. Any synchronous request can be turned into an asynchronous request by passing along a callback to run when the request completes. The function you pass as the `onComplete` argument is an example of this. This has the technical name of "[continuation passing](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/cps/)" (a "[continuation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/12/22/continuation-passing-style.aspx)" is, somewhat informally, "the rest of the calculation, from a give point forward").

Forget about call stacks for a moment. Pretend the `return` statement as just another function. This `return` function is a continuation; when it's called, the rest of the calculation happens. The first step in switching to asynchronous calls is to have your `GetUserId` function call the continuation passed in instead of special `return` continuation.

```
function GetUserId(succeed, fail)
{
  var resultreturned;
  var jsonRequest = new Request({url: myurl, async: false, onSuccess: function(result) {resultreturned = result;}, onFailure: fail}).get();
  succeed(resultreturned);
}
```

To finish the switch, pass the continuation on to `Request` rather than invoking it in `GetUserId`, and make the request asynchronous.

```
function GetUserId(succeed, fail)
{
  new Request({url: myurl, onSuccess: succeed, onFailure: fail}).get();
}

...
function checkoutOrLogin(userId, responseXML) {
    if (userId) {
        /* continue checkout */
    } else {
        /* display login form */
    }
}
GetUserId(checkoutOrLogin, function(xhr) {/* display error message */});
```

Comment: Got it. I did not realize I could not do the return inside the onComplete function. And I tried the jsonRequest.xhr.responseText and it worked. THANK YOU. (unfortunately I can't vote your question up because I don't have enough reputation...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is of the scope. In the case of the first example, you are returning value from an annonymous function that is not assigned to any variable.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess there is still a lot to learn about Ajax... :O)